# Array adapter, image downloader and internal storage

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, imagedownload

**Note**

> This question is not aiming code answers. It intend to get some ideas
>   for best code practices that deals with the problem proposed.

**Problem**

> List view that is connected as usual with array adapter of countries.
>   country object have 2 attributes. an image url and country name. at
>   the very first time images will be downloaded from the url and must be
>   saved on the internal memory. next time images will be loaded from the
>   internal memory if exist. otherwise, they will be downloaded.

What is the best structure to solve this problem?

**Spot lights**

> - a bitmap object is the container that a download steam will write to.
> - an image in the internal will also be sit to the bitmap object before we set bitmap to the image view.
> - (is this point optional) a bitmap ref. should be a member of the country class.
> - on download complete the downloaded image may and may not still needed because it's view is no longer visible (actually it is visible
>     but another country owns it). is it better to check that before we set
>     the image bitmap. or its better to just notify data changed.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library for image downloading
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It has tons of features, you can cache in memory or on disk, has image loading events, and a ton of more stuff.

Comment: downloading and saving the image itself is not my problem. that part already done. it's about handling updating images views and list view.

Comment: If you have an updated image, you will have to delete the image from the cache then redownload it. There is a util in the library to see if it exists in the cache.